# Google Play Console - Change Bad Behavior Threshold

Tags: android, google-play-console

I noticed that in the latest Google Play console, there is a "bad behavior threshold" for all of the "Android Vitals" metrics (e.g. ANRs, Crashes, Frozen Frames, etc.).  The threshold seems to be arbitrarily set by Google (e.g ANRs set to 0.48%).

Is there a way to change this "bad behavior threshold" to a different number? Or is this purely controlled by Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These thresholds are set by Google: `At the top of the Overview page, some metrics may be marked with a red error icon . This means the number shown is high compared to other apps—known as a bad behavior.`

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7385505?hl=en, see *Filter by bad behaviors* section

Comment: Are there any consequences to bad behavior? Like does Play Store stop rolling out my release or something like that?

Comment: @xjcl not sure, but quick googling suggested that apps might be less visible on Play store if they are considered to have "bad behavior".